# C# Entity Framework Add

Tags: c#

Использую .Net 4.5 и Entity Framework, при попытке добавления элемента вылетает DbUpdateException. Не могу понять почему.

```
string nameAlbum="Doors";

photoGaleryEntities photoGalery = new photoGaleryEntities();

photoGalery.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

photoGalery.ALBUMS.Add(new ALBUMS() { NAME = nameAlbum });

photoGalery.SaveChanges();
```

---

```
public partial class ALBUMS
{
    public ALBUMS()
    {
        this.PHOTOS = new HashSet<PHOTOS>();
    }

    public int ID_ALBUM { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PHOTOS> PHOTOS { get; set; }
}
```

---

innerexception(в бд у меня стоит автоинкремент на id)

> {"Невозможно вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в таблице \"ALBUMS\", когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF."}

Comment: Смотрите что написано в InnerException

Comment: Интересно, как еще выглядит класс ALBUMS и схема соответствующей таблицы в базе? Такое ощущение, что попытка присвоить значения null в поле таблицы, которое не может быть null

Answer (score 3):

Есть пара вариантов, почему ошибка:

1. Если используете подход Database-first и сначала создавали БД и импортировали её в edmx, то возможно сделали это до того, как поставили Identity на столбец. Удалите все таблицы из edmx и потом заново их добавьте.
2. Если вы используете подход Code-first, то вероятно не поставили нужный атрибут на свойство класса.
   Вроде бы это этот атрибут:

> [Key,
> DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]